# How to compare date values In dataGrid with current date?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have tried with

```
protected void gridCustomer_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      DateTime olddate = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[9].Text);
      // Error : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime./ 'DateTime today = DateTime.Now;'
      if (olddate > today)
      {
          Label status = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("lblStatus");
          status.Text = "AutoHold";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please re-format your code. What is your `e.Row.Cells[9].Text` value and what is your `CurrentCulture` exactly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: yes, what is the value stored in e.Row.Cells[9].Text ?

Comment: Convert string to date is a bad practice, if it can be avoided

Comment: This is the value stored '2015-03-28'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Convert.ToDateTime` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings *by default* if you don't provide any [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) as a second parameter.

That means, your `CurrentCulture` doesn't have `yyyy-MM-dd` as a [standard date and time format.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

In such a case, you can specify your string format with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx) methods like;

```
DateTime olddate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Row.Cells[9].Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out olddate))
{
    // Your olddate will be 28/03/2015 00:00:00
}
```

> but in old date getting '1/1/0001' where as in my grid cell i have
>   '4/1/2015' by above your mentioned code.

Clearly, your `4/1/2015` doesn't match with `yyyy-MM-dd` format, that why your `olddate` will be the default value of `DateTime` which is [`DateTime.MinValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) (`1/1/0001)`.

If your string can be more than one format, [`DateTime.TryParseExact` has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes formats as a string array. With that, you can specify all possible formats your string.

For example;

```
string s = "4/1/2015";
DateTime dt;
var formats = new string[]{"yyyy-MM-dd", "M/d/yyyy"};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // Your dt will be 01/04/2015 00:00:00
}
```

Comment: many many thanx, but I tried alredy with this also at yesterday dnt know why got error..

Comment: mean we get date in any format then sql will take in this format 'yyyy-mm-dd' ? because I gave input like 'dd/MMM/yyyy' in UI

Comment: @dawoodabbas I don't understand your second comment. You didn't even mentioned sql part in your question. A `DateTime` doesn't have _any_ implicit format. It just have date and time values. Formatting concept _only_ applies when you try to represent them. And SQL Server keeps `DateTime` values in a binary format that human can't read.

Comment: but in old date getting '1/1/0001' where as in my grid cell i have '4/1/2015' by above your mentioned code.

Comment: @dawoodabbas You didn't mentioned before your string _can_ have more than one format. Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: Actually i am inserting in to table from UI like this format 'dd-mmm-yyyy'. but its saving auto in table like this 'yyyy-mm-dd'. when i am binding into gridview showing like this. m/dd/yyyy. so that's why cant understood that with which format i have to compare?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
dateString = "2015-03-28";
format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
try {
  result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
  Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException) {
  Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
string res = "2012-07-08";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(res, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")); // can set any format
```

Comment: throwing same error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line in code

```
DateTime olddate = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Row.Cells[9].Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`Convert.ToDateTime` will throw exception if there is a difference in current culture and the format of date time string